# Unfortunately, (apps) has stopped

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and currently i'm trying to leran up Java by modifying some examples and then creating my own apps.
However, i keep coming to this error when i tried to lauch the apps. No error triggered at the coding site.
Can anyone help to look at this and tell me where the error is? Thanks in advance..
Below is my code in BMIcalculation.java :

```
package com.example.caloriescalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class BMIcalculation extends Activity
{
EditText weightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
EditText heightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
EditText ageE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageText);
EditText caloriesresult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);
RadioButton male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradio); 
RadioButton female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradio);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.bmilayout_main);     
    Button calories = (Button) findViewById(R.id.caloriesButton); 
    calories.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       {
         @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {    
                    int weight = 0, age = 0, height = 0, caloriesneed = 0;
                    String weightE, heightE, ageE;
                     weightE = getString(R.id.weightText);
                     heightE = getString(R.id.heightText);
                     ageE = getString(R.id.ageText);

                                if (weightE != "" && heightE != "" && ageE != "") 
                                {

                                    if (male.isSelected()) 
                                        {
                                            caloriesneed = (int) (655 + 9.6*weight + 1.8*height - 4.7*age);
                                            caloriesresult.setText(caloriesneed);
                                        }

                                    else if (female.isSelected())
                                        {
                                            caloriesneed = (int) Math.round (66 + 13.7*weight + 5*height - 6.8*age);
                                            caloriesresult.setText(caloriesneed);
                                        }
                                }

                }
       });
}

public void calculateClickHandler(View view) 
{
    // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button

if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) 
 {           
     // get the references to the widgets
     EditText weightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
     EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
     TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);

     // get the users values from the widget references

     float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
     float height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());

     // calculate the BMI value

     float bmiValue = calBMI(weight, height);

     // interpret the category based on the BMI value
     String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

     // now set the value in the result text

     resultText.setText("Your current BMI :" + bmiValue + " - " + bmiInterpretation);
 }
}

   // the formula to calculate the BMI index
   // check for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index
   private float calBMI (float weight, float height) {

    return (float) (weight *10000 / (height * height));
   }  
   // interpret what BMI means
   private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) 
   {

    if (bmiValue < 16) 
    {
     return "Severely underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 18.5) {

     return "Underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 25) {

     return "Normal";
    } else if (bmiValue < 30) {

     return "Overweight";
    } else {
     return "Obese";
    }

   }
```

}

Comment: You're trying to learn android and not java, AFAICT from your code. *Java != Android*.

Comment: android is tought to learn begin from developer.android.com so you can

Comment: Apart from the given answers, Java (and hence, Android) cannot compare the `String` using `==` or `!=` (it is possible, but definitely not the one you expect). Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs..ya, i'm learning Android, with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all your initialization inside `onCreate`

```
EditText weightE ;
EditText heightE ;
EditText ageE ;
EditText caloriesresult;
RadioButton male ;
RadioButton female; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.bmilayout_main); // must be first 
weightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText); // then initialize your views
heightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
ageE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageText);
caloriesresult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);
male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradio); 
female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradio);
...// rest of the code
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned inthe current inflated layout. So you need to set the content of the layout first and the initialize your views. If not you get NPE

Edit:

You also have

```
 EditText weightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
 EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
```

which is not required

You can use `weightE` and `heightE`  which is already initialized with id `wightText` and `heightText`. Since it is class member and already initialized no need to initialize again

Edit 2:

All though you have this in onClick rename the variables as you have editexts also with the same name to avoid confusion

```
  String weightE, heightE, ageE;
  weightE = getString(R.id.weightText);
  heightE = getString(R.id.heightText);
```

And to comapre strings use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase`.

```
if (!weightE.equals("") && (!heightE.equals("") && (!ageE.equals(""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for edit 1 & 2. It works now. Btw for the !weightE.equals("") part, what does the "!" infront means?

Answer (score 1):

Without logcat error, I can only tell you this:

Move

```
weightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
heightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
ageE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageText);
caloriesresult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);
male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradio); 
female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradio);
```

part to `onCreate` after

```
setContentView(R.layout.bmilayout_main);
```

You are trying to find views before setContentView. And declare outside onCreate where you have initialized. Correct that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ya this helps :). I can now launch and go into the apps after moved that part.

Comment: Good @user2943793 tell me if you face problem again

Answer (score 1):

You can not initialized Components before setting the content View in `OnCreate()`.
   So just declare it before onCreate() & initialise all components after setting the content View in OnCreate().

```
package com.example.caloriescalculator;


public class BMIcalculation extends Activity
{
EditText weightE;
EditText heightE ;
EditText ageE ;
EditText caloriesresult ;
RadioButton male; 
RadioButton female;

Button calories;

 EditText weightText ;
 EditText heightText ;
 TextView resultText ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.bmilayout_main);   

 weightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
 heightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
 ageE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageText);
 caloriesresult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);
 male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradio); 
 female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradio);  
 calories = (Button) findViewById(R.id.caloriesButton); 


    calories.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       {
         @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {    
                    // rest of your code
```

Comment: Oh. I follow your suggestion and moved that part. It works now. Thanks for your prompt reply and great help :)

Comment: Happy to help!!If my answr solves your issue then u can accept it as an Answer.